# Query help, rank function maybe?

Tags: sql

rank function? can anybody assist me with this.  I'd like my query to only return the lowest date for the P0260 field, and the lowest date for the painting field.

```
JOB              ID     LINE                                   ORDER    RCVD     USE DATE
P0260           61785   1                   2400    24  10/26/2012
P0260           63462   3                   2400    24  11/14/2012
P0260           66372   1                   1   0   2/15/2013
P0260           66371   1                   5   0   3/1/2013
PAINTING    12246   1                   29  27  11/30/2006
PAINTING    30885   1                   160 0   9/29/2009
Painting    30885   2                   160 0   9/29/2009
PAINTING    31155   1                   25  0   11/6/2009
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: And what is the RDBMS that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, without knowing wich RDBMS (and version) you are using, this solution should work on most of them:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM YourTable A
INNER JOIN (SELECT JOB, MIN([USE DATE]) MinUseDate
            FROM YourTable
            GROUP BY JOB) B
    ON A.JOB = B.JOB AND A.[USE DATE] = B.MinUseDate
```

Comment: Yes I did Juergen, I was trying to use a rank function though.  Lamark, I tried your solution, all of these fields are coming from a different layered query.  Here is what I have, which is giving me a syntax error:

Comment: @user2084783 Well, the way you are adding information is confusing. You should add your query on the question, not as an answer, and also post the syntax error that you are getting. Also, I imagine that `query2` is a subquery, so you are probably missing an alias (but that would be more clear when you post the error you are getting). Oh, and since you are updating your post, please tell us wich RDBMS and version you are using (Oracle, SQL Server 2005, MySQL, etc)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT query2.PART_ID, query2.ID, query2.LINE_NO, query2.DEL_SCHED_LINE_NO, query2.SYSADM_PURC_LINE_DEL.ORDER_QTY, query2.RECEIVED_QTY, query2.DESIRED_RECV_DATE, query2.SYSADM_PURC_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY, query2.TOTAL_RECEIVED_QTY, query2.[USE DATE]
FROM query2
INNER JOIN (SELECT  query2.PART_ID, MIN(query2.[USE DATE]) MinUseDate
FROM query2
GROUP BY  PART_ID) B
ON query2.PART_ID = B.PART_ID AND  query2.[USE DATE] = B.MinUseDate;